# How to enable uploading files by dragging and dropping them using asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer

One of my clients has requested the functionality of uploading documents by dragging and dropping them in the browser window. The website is being built with ASP.NET 3.5. I know of the 'dragdropupload' add-in for firefox, which allows dropping files on an upload control, but I also need it to work in Internet Explorer.

Does anybody know of a way to programmatically enable this? Or are there perhaps any third party controls available (preferably free/open source)? It is acceptable if it is only possible to drop the file on an upload control. I cannot use any browser extensions like Silverlight or Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done i IE without ActiveX, or Silverlight

Comment: IE doesn't support that feature of HTML5 I think. Maybe IE9 but I'm not sure